# getJSON returning multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This works fine, alert the date of the 3º item from "eventos"

```
var eventos;
$.getJSON('/Pelotero/Modulos/Includes/Eventos/Ajax_Leer_Datos.php', function(data)
    {
    eventos = data;
    alert(eventos[3].Fecha);
    });
```

But I need this to access "eventos" out of getJSON function:

```
var eventos;
$.getJSON('/Pelotero/Modulos/Includes/Eventos/Ajax_Leer_Datos.php', function(data)
    {
    eventos = data;
    });

alert(eventos[3].Fecha);
```

Chorme says " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined "

Comment: Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming. You can't.

Comment: Also: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Ok, im on it. Thanks